# How to list files that can be imported from within cypher-shell?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, ls, cypher-3.1, cypher-shell

How can I run common Terminal commands (or equivalent command) such as `ls` for listing importable files from within Cypher-shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cypher-shell` just provides a way to execute Cypher queries from the command line.  It is not a general-purpose shell, like say `bash`, and does not provide any way to directly access the filesystem.